# Is there a way to get the docker daemon to bind to a certain NIC?

Tags: networking, network-interface, docker

I would like to start the docker daemon so that it binds to a specific network card on my machine.

I don't see any flags on [dockerd](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/) to do this.  Is this possible?

Comment: Do you have more than one NIC bound to the same IP address?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick nope, two nics, each with its own IP address.